# Creating a Jar of test binaries - Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm using the latest version of Gradle (milestone 9), and I'm trying to figure out how to create a Jar of all test binaries.

From what I've found on the internet, the following should work:

```
task packageTests(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.test.classes
}
```

However I am getting a -

> Cannot get the value of write-only property 'classes' on source set
>   test.

What is the correct way of coding what I'm trying to achieve?

Is the property 'classes' somehow deprecated now ?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Changing `sourceSets.test.classes` to `sourceSets.test.output` fixes the problem.

Comment: This is due to a change in the behaviour of Gradle between versions

Comment: Thank you for answering your own questions for others to find.

Comment: What version of Gradle had the change in behavior?

Comment: Can you provide a full answer with both Groovy and Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 8):

In 2021 there is the Kotlin DSL now, so the latest answer looks like:

```
tasks.register<Jar>("packageTests") {
    from(sourceSets.test.get().output)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it with Gradle / Groovy like this:

https://github.com/tomasbjerre/gradle-scripts/commit/d550e6bf79574b4920b7910e48ebd94ca959cece

```
  task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    classifier = 'test'
    from sourceSets.test.allSource
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

with gradle 8 looks like this:

```
tasks.register('testJar', Jar) {
    dependsOn classes
    archiveClassifier = 'test'
    from sourceSets.test.allSource
}

tasks.named('assemble').configure {
    dependsOn 'testJar'
}
```

Comment: Cannot get the value of write-only property 'classes' for source set 'test' of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSet.