# Gradle : sourceSets.test.classes not found

Tags: gradle

I am trying to get my one of my projects (ProjectA) to generate a jar file containing all the test classes so that it can be used in ProjectB.

I did a bit of research and found this as possible solution: [Create test jar artifact in gradle](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/11/gradle-goodness-create-jar-artifact.html). That says that the following code snippet should do the trick.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task testJar(type: Jar) {
   classifier = 'tests'
   from sourceSets.test.classes
}
```

However, when I add the above to my `build.gradle`, I get the following error message:

> - What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle_project'.
>
> Could not find property 'sourceSets' on task ':testJar'.

I have searched on both Google and the Gradle documentation for more information but either it has been removed without documenting it anywhere that I could find or I am using it wrong. I am suspecting the latter, just don't know what I am doing wrong.

I have tried the same code snippet inside my`subprojects{}` section but then I got the following error message:

> - What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle_project'.
>
> Cannot get the value of write-only property 'classes' on source set test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it with the steps below:

Step 1: Move the code snippet inside the `subprojects{}` section

Step 2: `sourceSets.test.classes` has been removed. `sourceSets.test.output` seems to do the trick. Found this: [Creating a Jar of test binaries - Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034084/creating-a-jar-of-test-binaries-gradle)