# Android Studio refuses to run main()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Repro steps:

1. Start a new project in Android Studio (with the latest update);
2. Make a new class and add main() as usual;
3. Right-click class to run main() as a test.

```java
package test;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Usually I expect I can just `System.out.printLn("Hello World")` but this time, no matter if it's a new project, I get the following error:

```
2:34:23 PM: Executing task 'Test.main()'...

Executing tasks: [Test.main()] in project C:\Users\regan\Desktop\events\MyApplication


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\regan\AppData\Local\Temp\Test_main__2.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:Test.main()'.
   > SourceSet with name 'test' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 0s
2:34:24 PM: Task execution finished 'Test.main()'.
```

I am *fairly* new to Java after years of C# in Unity and have no idea what all this stuff is trying to tell me. I have googled but the closest I found was a way to HIDE this error (assuming code was still compiling). I need this code to at least compile.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835034/gradle-sourcesets-test-classes-not-found

Comment: I'm struggling to interpret the answer to that one. I actually went through this process last week just fine, but today I tried, after Android Studio updated and that seems to be the only difference. I've no clue what the "subprojects{} section" is though.

Comment: This is telling you that you created an Android project but that Android applications use the Android lifecycle to run, not `main`.

Answer (score 65):

> **Quick Fix :**   You can run using **Run with Coverage.**. See Image Below.

[image: J]

> **Permanent Solution:**  Add `<option name="delegatedBuild" value="false" />` and sync project.

inside File `gradle.xml` under path `E:\Project\.idea\gradle.xml`. See Image below.

[image]

Comment: This started happening for me right after upgrade to the latest version of kotlin.

Comment: The same, happened after update to Kotlin 1.4.20-release-Studio4.1-1. Gradle option helped, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Two years later and Intellij still have the same bug :-(

Answer (score 34):

Open "gradle.xml" File in this path :

```
.idea/gradle.xml
```

Add the following line before ***</GradleProjectSettings/>***

```
<option name="delegatedBuild" value="false" />
```

That is it , it worked for me.

Comment: This is correct. I tested as well  Run with Coverage also works.

Comment: this is the right answer! kudos.
But what actually does it?

Answer (score 23):

The app module is an android library and expects android lifecycle methods such as onCreate() etc for successful execution. If you want to execute plain java code one option is to add a java library to the project using File -> New Module -> Java Library and add the main method there:

```
package com.example.lib;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

This would work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 18):

Try to run it with "coverage". I don't have any explanation, but it works!

Comment: this is the correct answer! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I'm currently using Android Studio Version **4.0.1**

1. after creating the project, you should go to tab
   **File ==> New ==> New Module...**
   [image: image one]
2. on "**Create New Module/ Selecte Module Type**":
3. Select **Java or Kotlin Library**
   [image: image 2] [image: image 3]
4. After it finish, go to javalib folder/ module that you have created.
5. Create Java file on there.
   [image: image 4]
6. try to run it

Comment: glad it helps :D

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem momentarily as well

I found when I changed Gradle to offline and then back online again then updated Gradle and made sure the connection and proxy settings were correct, things started working normally

Answer (score 3):

Avoid naming the class name as Test, Android studio somehow will get screwed when you name class as Test.

Comment: Hello ferraro ! It is best to give a comment to the question if your answer is short and does not solve the question fully!

Comment: I am grateful all the same. TY for that info :)

I don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: @ReganMusic No problem, Good to know my answer helped.

Answer (score 2):

If the module is from an android application or library it is not allowed to run the main; because what is expected is navigate transitions between stages of the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

In the following cases of modules with these plugins applied, the main can NOT be run.

### build.gradle.kts (:appAndroid)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
}
```

### build.gradle.kts (:libraryAndroid)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
}
```

### build.gradle.kts (:kmmShared)

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}
```

If the purpose of running the main was to test things, what you really have to do is use the sourceSets of `test`.

---

## If the module is from a Java or Kotlin library, running the main is allowed so the error would not exist.

The following applied plugins describe a JVM library:

### build.gradle.kts (:jvmLibrary)

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("kotlin")
}
```

---

Finally, if using the `test` sourceSets or creating a JVM module was not enough for you, there is a 'hack' which is weak because it depends on the IDE (It does not work in KMM modules).

### .idea/gradle.xml

```
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>

        <option name="delegatedBuild" value="false" />

      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

GL

Answer (score 2):

I have not much idea about it as I am very new in Android development and Android Studio. But after reading some solution over the internet and watchin some Youtube Videos, I have fixed it.

In app/build.gradle under dependencies for me
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1' - this was there

I changed it to
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

rebuilt the project and run, it worked for me..

I guess there must be some android studio update (in the latest version) was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I also got stuck in this problem. I am using **Android Studio Arctic Fox** in **Macbook Pro M1**. I have also tried to add New Module and Select **Java and Kotlin Library** and edited the configuration but it did not work for me. But it did work on my Windows System.

In macbook, I simply downgraded the dependancy in my App level **build.gradle** file
from

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

and run my Java Class as **Run as Coverage** and it worked.

Comment: Magicly this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, but this way the error went away.
In the priject field right click on app,
select
New module, then chosse java or kotlin Library.
After that open your brand new module.
Inside public class write main and hit enter.
Now inside your main class you are able to write your code.as you wished.