# Spring Boot: Launch other main method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, launch

I'm trying to launch another main method in another (test) jar.
According to [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034084/creating-a-jar-of-test-binaries-gradle),I added

```
task packageTests(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.test.output
 }
```

to `build.gradle` to package all test resources and classes into a jar.
Then I executed
`gradle bootRepackage` which creates `MyWS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and
`gradle packageTests` which creates `MyWS.jar`.

Thereafter I copied both jars in a folder and created an `application.properties` with

```
loader.path=lib:/*,MyWS.jar
loader.main=db.DBTest
```

After reading the [boot manual appendix](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features), I try to launch the other main (in `MyWS.jar/db.DBTest`) with

```
java -cp ./MyWS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;./MyWS.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher -Dloader.main=db.DBTest
```

but the 'old' `Start-Class` of `MyWS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`s `MANIFEST` is still launched.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I can't remember the precedence rules off-hand, but have you tried it with the test jar first?

Comment: I tried, but I think it's related to settings this `Start-Class`