# Package tests for execution in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I have a gradle project that contains a suit of tests, that can be launched with a command:
gradlew clean :mymodule:test

I need to build a jar, that can be executed in the same way and launch tests. I found instruction for creating a jar of test binaries here [Creating a Jar of test binaries - Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034084/creating-a-jar-of-test-binaries-gradle).

```
task packageTests(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from sourceSets.test.output
}
```

However the resulting jar contains only test classes and resources, no dependent libraries or main application source code.
How can I create an executable test jar?

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I wouldn't use `classifier='tests'` as that is usually reserved for a jar containing test classes without dependencies. Possibly `uber-tests` or `fat-tests` is better as uber-jar and fat-jar are common names given to this type of jar. You could do something like

```
task uberTestJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn testClasses
    classifier = 'uber-tests'
    sourceSets.main.output.each {
        from it
    }
    sourceSets.test.output.each {
        from it
    }
    configurations.testRuntime.each { File f ->
        if (f.name.endsWith('.jar')) {
            from zipTree(f)
        } else {
            from f
        }
    }
}
```

There's also the [shadow jar plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)

Comment: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'uberTestJar' property 'rootSpec$1' during up-to-date check. Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'my.jar'.

Comment: Updated to use the `testRuntime` configuration plus the outputs from the `main` and `test` source sets to avoid a dependency on the project jar for `UP-TO-DATE` checks. Also added a dependency on the `testClasses` task.

Comment: This code produces a thin jar no different from test jar for me. It dos not include test runTime dependencies.